# How to kill a process starting with name "a123" of a specific user "xyz" using Python

Tags: python, process, kill

A particular user named "xyz" with file starting "a123" is running. I need to kill that particular running process of that particular user using Python program.

On searching, I could see multiple programs to kill a process using process id (only) in python.

Kindly provide a solution in detail for the problem i have mentioned ?

Comment: you could look at the python module `psutil` and its documentation. It allows you to get a list of all running processes and their names. so you can search for the right process and kill it.

Comment: if you use Linux then you can use system command `ps aux` to display processes with its users and ids so you can find `id` (using user and name) and kill it. But it could be easier to use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are we able to get filename using process name (actual file which is running under that process) or vice-versa ? Is that possible ? i have checked psutil documentation where open_files() could fetch multiple paths along with the actual file path. Hard to distinguish. Is there any simpler way to obtain it ?